# ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined (this error in node script not in node REPL)

Tags: node.js, express

[here i am unable to use __dirname is express and getting this refrencerror please help me out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boq7b.png)

Comment: Hey, are you sure this is the right screenshot? Looks unrelated...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the screenshot of an HTML file is the correct screenshot, `__dirname` is part of nodejs and will not work in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` is part of NodeJS, the issue is you are using front-end JS I assume, which won't work because it's a different runtime environment